# Fixing route problems in ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a ROR newbie and I've somehow broken the create and edit functionalities within my app. I have individual pages for each artwork I've uploaded, a _form that enables editing of those artworks (and their original creation), and two different index pages: one index page that's pretty (on the app's home page), and one that's just a big table with all the info for each artwork (for the backend).

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "pages#home"

  get "artworks" => "artworks#index"
  # post "artworks" => "artworks#index"

  resources :artworks, path: ''

  get "about" => "pages#about"
end
```

artworks_controller.rb

```
class ArtworksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_artwork, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /artworks
  # GET /artworks.json
  def index
    @artworks = Artwork.all
  end

  # GET /artworks/1
  # GET /artworks/1.json
  def show
    @artwork = Artwork.friendly.find(params[:id])
    if request.path != artwork_path(@artwork)
      redirect_to @artwork, status: :moved_permanently
    end
  end

  # GET /artworks/new
  def new
    @artwork = Artwork.new
  end

  # GET /artworks/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /artworks
  # POST /artworks.json
  def create
    @artwork = Artwork.new( artwork_params )

    respond_to do |format|
      if @artwork.save
        format.html { redirect_to @artwork, notice: 'Artwork was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @artwork }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @artwork.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /artworks/1
  # PATCH/PUT /artworks/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @artwork.update(artwork_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @artworks, notice: 'Artwork was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @artwork }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @artwork.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /artworks/1
  # DELETE /artworks/1.json
  def destroy
    @artwork.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to artworks_url, notice: 'Artwork was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_artwork
      @artwork = Artwork.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def artwork_params
      params.require(:artwork).permit(:title, :image, :genre, :category, :medium, :slug, :availability, :date, :height, :width)
    end
end
```

pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @artworks = Artwork.all
  end

  def about 
    end

end
```

index.html.rb (in views/artworks)

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-4">
          <h1>Listing artworks</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-md-offset-6">
          <%= link_to 'New Artwork', new_artwork_path, class:"btn btn-default" %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Image</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Genre</th>
              <th>Category</th>
              <th>Medium</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Dimensions</th>
              <th>Availability</th>
              <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            <% @artworks.each do |artwork| %>
              <tr>
                <td><%= link_to image_tag(artwork.image.url(:thumb)), artwork %></td>
                <td><%= artwork.title %></td>
                <td><%= artwork.genre %></td>
                <td><%= artwork.category %></td>
                <td><%= artwork.medium %></td>
                <td><%= artwork.date %></td>
                <td><%= artwork.height %> x <%= artwork.width %></td>
                <td><%= artwork.availability %> </td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_artwork_path(artwork) %></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            <% end %>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>


    <br>

_form.html.rb
<%= simple_form_for @artwork, :html => {:multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <% if @artwork.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@artwork.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this artwork from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @artwork.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <%= f.input :image %>
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <%= f.input :title %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= f.input :genre, :collection => ['Landscape', 'Still life', 'Figure', 'Interior'], :include_blank => false, :as => :radio_buttons %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= f.input :category, :collection => ['Painting', 'Drawing', 'Sculpture', 'Print', 'Mixed media'], :include_blank => false, :as => :radio_buttons %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= f.input :medium, :collection => ['Oil on paper', 'Oil on canvas', 'Oil on canvas mounted on panel', 'Watercolor', 'Ink wash', 'Charcoal', 'Graphite', 'Oil pastel'] %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= f.input :date, :include_blank => true, as: :string, start_year: Time.now.year - 100, end_year: Time.now.year, order: [ :year, :month, :day,], hint: 'Order: Year, month, date' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= f.input :height %>
      <%= f.input :width %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= f.input :availability, :collection => ['Available for purchase','Private collection','Not for sale'],  :as => :radio_buttons %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <%= f.input :notes %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-10">
      <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  </div>


<!--
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :image %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :genre %><br>
    <%= f.select :genre, ['Landscape', 'Still life', 'Figure', 'Interior'] %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :category %><br>
    <%= f.select :category, ['Painting', 'Drawing', 'Sculpture', 'Print', 'Mixed media'] %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :medium %><br>
    <%= f.select :medium, ['Oil on paper', 'Oil on canvas', 'Oil on canvas mounted on panel', 'Watercolor', 'Ink wash', 'Charcoal', 'Graphite'] %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div> -->
<% end %>
```

and home.html.erb (in views/pages)

```
<div id="artworks" class="transitions-enabled">
    <% @artworks.each do |artwork| %>
        <div class="box">
                <%= link_to image_tag(artwork.image.url(:medium)), artwork %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

model: artwork.rb

```
class Artwork < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: [:slugged, :history]
  def slug_candidates
    [
      :title,
      [:title, :genre],
      [:title, :genre, :category],
      [:title, :genre, :category, :medium]
    ]
  end

  def previous
    Artwork.where(["id < ?", id]).order('id').last
  end

  def next
    Artwork.where(["id > ?", id]).first
  end

end
```

I'm using a few gems that I like (friendly_id), but somehow I've broken the form because I get the error "ActionController::ActionControllerError in ArtworksController#update
Cannot redirect to nil!" related to line 49:

```
format.html { redirect_to @artworks, notice: 'Artwork was successfully updated.' }
```

When I create a new artwork, I see this error: "Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/artworks""

rake routes:

```
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern         Controller#Action
    artworks GET    /artworks(.:format) artworks#index
        root GET    /                   pages#home
             GET    /                   artworks#index
             POST   /                   artworks#create
 new_artwork GET    /new(.:format)      artworks#new
edit_artwork GET    /:id/edit(.:format) artworks#edit
     artwork GET    /:id(.:format)      artworks#show
             PATCH  /:id(.:format)      artworks#update
             PUT    /:id(.:format)      artworks#update
             DELETE /:id(.:format)      artworks#destroy
       about GET    /about(.:format)    pages#about
```

Can anyone help me see what I've done wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is @artworks in `redirect_to @artworks` , try replacing with `redirect_to artworks_url`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
redirect_to @artworks
```

to

```
redirect_to artworks_url
```

also modify routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "pages#home"

  resources :artworks

  get "about" => "pages#about"
end
```

Comment: Thanks @pkrawat1, this does get the editing to work (though I may need to configure the route differently). I just added some more detail to the original post about creating a new record which is giving me an error too. Any thoughts? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also  redirect to  artworks_path if you want to reflect to index page after creation in create action

Comment: Added rake routes to the original post. I changed three (create, edit, destroy) to artworks_url, but I'm getting a routing error: No route matches [POST] "/artworks"

Comment: did you update the routes file as above? , I have removed this line `get "artworks" => "artworks#index"`, since this route is generated by 'resources :artworks
'

Comment: I did, and that works, but it changes where certain actions lead. It looks like routes.rb is the main place I'm screwing things up, so I'll probably just try to read more about that. get "artworks" => "artworks#index" was my way of pulling up the table page, and I had resources :artworks, path '' because I want the urls to be domain.com/artwork-name-here instead of domain.com/artworks/artwork-name-here

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by doing a few things:

1. Created a new 'admin.html.erb' page within my artworks/ folder. I cut and pasted the code from index.html.erb into it.
2. Cut code out of my home.html.erb file and pasted into the index.html.erb file.
3. Removed the 'def home' method from the pages_controller.
4. Rewrote routes as follows:

   root "artworks#index"
   get "about" => "pages#about"
   get "admin" => "artworks#admin"

[This other thread I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248413/what-is-the-proper-way-to-organize-two-different-views-of-the-same-model) helped me sort out this issue. @Ajay's and @Deep's responses helped me think this through.