# What is the proper way to organize two different views of the same model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ROR newbie. I have read a lot, but I think I'm slow to absorb. I'm trying to create a web app with two different views of the same content:

1. A page full of artworks for visitors to browse by image (at the root of the site).
2. A page with a table listing out those same artworks and showing all the relevant attributes I've defined for them (medium, etc.) so I can review data associated with each artwork. This is supposed to be my super-lightweight admin page.

My questions are:

1. Since I generated this site from a scaffold, I'm currently using views/artworks/index.html.erb as the admin table view (supposed to be private), and I created a 'home' page and added some code to the 'home' view (and pages_controller) to make the artworks show up there (for the public). **Am I doing this right? Is this a good method of organization?**
2. I've installed devise and successfully hidden links for editing artworks on the page behind a sign in, but I don't know the proper way to cordon off portions of the app (e.g. the admin table page, edit pages, etc.) from the rest of the world. Should I be putting these pages in a different folder? **How do I make these pages private?**

Here are some snippets:
home.html.erb

```
<div id="artworks" class="transitions-enabled">
    <% @artworks.each do |artwork| %>
        <div class="box">
                <%= link_to image_tag(artwork.image.url(:medium)), artwork %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

artworks/index.html.erb:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-4">
      <h1>Listing artworks</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-md-offset-6">
      <%= link_to 'New Artwork', new_artwork_path, class:"btn btn-default" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Image</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Genre</th>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Medium</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Dimensions</th>
          <th>Availability</th>
          <th>Rating</th>
          <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <% @artworks.each do |artwork| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= link_to image_tag(artwork.image.url(:thumb)), artwork %></td>
            <td><%= artwork.title %></td>
            <td><%= artwork.genre %></td>
            <td><%= artwork.category %></td>
            <td><%= artwork.medium %></td>
            <td><%= artwork.date %></td>
            <td><%= artwork.height %> x <%= artwork.width %></td>
            <td><%= artwork.availability %> </td>
            <td><%= artwork.rating %> </td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_artwork_path(artwork) %></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

both pages_controller.rb and artworks_controller.rb have code like this:

```
def index
    if params[:tag]
      @artworks = Artwork.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @artworks = Artwork.all
    end
  end
```

pages_controller.rb:

```
def home
    @artworks = Artwork.all
  end
```

and the routes.rb:

```
get 'tagged' => 'artworks#index', :as => 'tagged'

  devise_for :users
  # get "artworks" => "artworks#index"
  # post "artworks" => "artworks#index"

  root "pages#home"
  get "about" => "pages#about"
  #get "users" => "users#index"

  resources :artworks
```

Thanks in advance for your patience and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

artworks/index.html.erb

```
<div class= 'row'> 
  <!-- your other source code goes here --> 
</div>
```

You want this page to be private until the user is logged in. Then you can try this :

```
<% if current_user.present? %> 
 <div class= 'row'> 
   <!-- your other source code goes here --> 
 </div>
<% end %>
```

This div will be visible only if the user is logged in. for not yet signed in users this page will be private.

In order to make the edit option private :

```
<% if current_user.present? %> 
  <div id="artworks" class="transitions-enabled">
    <% @artworks.each do |artwork| %>
        <div class="box">
          <%= link_to image_tag(artwork.image.url(:medium)), artwork %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In any case if you want to public/private few sections then just wrap it inside the conditional if statements for views.

Still if anyone wishes then he can hit the url and enter into your action directly, in that case you can put condition in the controller.

```
 before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:action_1, :action_2]
```

Further if you need to keep things private on basis of user role, you can
always chose for cancan gem.

Comment: thanks for this. It helped me sort through the first part of my problem (how to arrange the pages within the app), and consequently solved some other problems I was having with routes, etc.

Comment: Most welcome @PeterBentley. Consider accepting answer if this has fixed your issue :)

Comment: For posterity: as to overall site organization I found it much easier to follow this advice and create a separate admin.html.erb page, cut/paste the table into the admin page, and cut/paste the home page to artworks/index, which helped me then cleanup my routes. I also followed advice [from here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Set-up-devise-as-a-single-user-system), and designated one user as the admin through the rails console (both in dev and prod).

Answer (score 1):

This can be the right way. But you have installed devise and hidden the links. But someone can directly hit the url. You need to add some authorization code which will take care that only admin user can edit the artworks. This can be done in many ways. If you have a simple application you can just add a before filter in which you can check if the user is admin then only he can access the page and call that on edit and update action. Either you can also use any authorization gem like Authority or so if it needs many roles. Hope this helps.

For making the code DRY:

```
before_filter :set_artworks, :only => [:home, :index]

private

 def set_artworks
  @artworks = Artworks.all
 end
```

Comment: Definitely helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like my '@artworks = Artwork.all' being written in two places isn't very DRY. How should I arrange things to avoid this?

Comment: You can add this in a before_filter too. I have updated the answer for same

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of maintaining privileges is using [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) gem.

Install it via bundler and generate model via `rails generate cancan:ability`. Then you have to distinguish admin users from others (e.g you can add integer "role" to User model) and write something like this in `models/ability.rb#initialize`

```
if user.admin?
    can :manage, :all
else
    can :read, Artwork
end
```

and modify controllers like this:

```
def index
authorize! :edit, Artwork
if params[:tag]
  @artworks = Artwork.tagged_with(params[:tag])
else
  @artworks = Artwork.all
end
```

end

This will throw an exception if not admin user will want to go to index. You can use redirect_to to inform user about that error. Add this to ApplicationController:

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to root_url, :alert => exception.message
end
```